# c++,list и структура

Tags: c++

Мне надо пробежаться по list,который хранит имеет тип структуры.
Каким образом можно в цикле перебрать каждый элемент и распечатать?
Допустим структура:

```
struct Mywork {
    string str;
    int numb1;
    int numb2;
};
```

Я объявляю list и в цикле добавляю элементы:

```
Mywork *mass = new Mywork[number];
list <Mywork> listok;
list<Mywork>::iterator ptr;

for (int i=0; i < number; i++) {
        Mywork temp;
        cin >>temp.str >>temp.numb1 >> temp.numb2;
        listok.push_back(temp);
    }
```

Но брать так элементы через итератор не получается и выдает ошибку:

```
for (ptr = listok.begin(); ptr != listok.end(); ptr++) {
        cout << *ptr.str<<*ptr.numb1<<*ptr.numb2;
    }
```

Каким образом можно обойти элементы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скобки забыли: `(*ptr).countPeople`.

Еще лучше вот так: `ptr->countPeople`.

Comment: Точно!Благодарю

Comment: @Вячеслав Жмякните зеленую галочку слева чтобы отметить вопрос как решенный.